# How to correlate qTest test cases with junit test results (reported by Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, junit, qtest

I have a pre-existing body of automated test cases that are executed by a Jenkins job. Engineers are happy with the Jenkins reports, but managers want to use qTest Manager reporting to get a unified view of automated + manual tests.

There is quite a bit of overlap between my automated tests and the manual tests, but in prior months the naming conventions diverged. I can't seem to find a way in qTest match up or link two test cases. Is there a magic to naming them? Part of the issue seems to be that the qTest plugin for Jenkins prefixes all the test cases with `suiteName#` so tests that would otherwise have identical names are munged.

Example: The Jenkins test case is named "QA-182_pg.1 single new guest can pay ACH deposit" --in script filename "QA-182.robot"

The plugin submits that to qTest "Suites.QA-182#QA-182_pg.1 single new guest can pay ACH deposit"

Meanwhile, the manual test in qTest is named "0001- (E2E) 1 new guest, partial pmt eCheck QA-182" --granted they are nowhere close to being *identically* named, but they do share a common substring "QA-182"

The specter of renaming hundreds of tests does not appeal. Is there a way to link them based on a regex or substring match?

Comment: At a different company, we use [TestRail.io](http://testrail.io/) which has the ability to specify a "testCaseID" in each automation test case. This clearly links automated test cases with the test case tracking. More info at https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/getting-started/introduction